# POST body request is badly built using NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject

Tags: swift

I am trying to create POST requests using `NSMutableURLRequest` but passing a `NSData` object to its `HTTPBody` does not behave as expected.

Here is what I do:

```
    guard let url = NSURL(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Error: Cannot create URL")
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let params = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(options, options: [])

        let urlRequest:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = method

        if method != "GET" {
            urlRequest.HTTPBody = params
        }

        return urlRequest

    } catch {
        print("Error: Cannot parse options data into JSON")
        return nil
    }
```

Here is what I get:

```
#<Hashie::Mash {"token":"MVgutecI0y5AzJ8KcIgkxT56mwEh","email":"adrien.giboire@gmail.com","password":"adichris"}=nil>
```

My server is written in Ruby. Here is how I fetch it:

```
puts params.inspect
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem ? What error do you get? Are you aware there is a plain text password in params ?

Comment: @SamuelD I got no error. The problem is I'm not getting a well formed JSON in my request. Regarding the password, it's used nowhere but thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are posting JSON you must set the request's `Content-Type` header to `application/json` before returning it.

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: I knew it was something that simple. Thanks!